# How to create a main menu with various CMS pages in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, menu

How do I add pages and links to the main menu in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `Observer` on the `top_menu_before` event.  I only included the two files that do the heavy lifting, but that is because I assume that you know how to [Create a Module](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/)

**app/code/Vendor/Menu/etc/events.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before">
    <observer name="vendor_menu_observer" instance="Vendor\Menu\Observer\TopmenuBefore" />
  </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Menu/Observer/TopmenuBefore.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Menu\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class TopmenuBefore implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
        public function __construct() {}


    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return $this
     */
        public function execute(EventObserver $observer) {
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
                $menu = $observer->getMenu();
                $tree = $menu->getTree();

                $data = [
                        'name' => __('Name to Display'),
                        'id' => 'identifier-for-later-use',
                        'url' => '/path-to-page',
                        'is_active' => 0 // if you want to add an 'active' css-class, use 1 
                ];

                $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
                $menu->addChild($node);

                return $this;
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this pull all CMS pages?  I'm not very versed on how the functions work, but I don't see any loop.

Comment: @Jason This pulls a cms_block with `identifier` =  the `id` node, and links to the `url` node, with the title from the `name` node, all defined in the `$data` array.  It is only one, but you can easily copy the code a second time to add more than one menu-item.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, thanks for clarifying that part about adding extra links.  As of right now, I was able to simply create a cms-block and insert into the nav through the default.xml file.  Unfortunately my links placed into the nav in this manner are directing to https://url.com/undefined.  ONLY the links placed in the cms block and only in the mobile menu.

Answer (score -1):

I developed a FOSS module that allows to set redirects for categories.

This steps were taken:

- Add an attribute `redirect_url`
- If set, replace the category URL with that URL
- Hook into is-active logic to mark the right menu entry as active

The module can be found on github

https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect